# How to bake high poly to low poly decimation into high res normal / bump map in 2.8 or higher?

Tags: modeling

As the title suggests.  I know there is a ton of data on how to do high poly to low poly in 2.79 and below, but 2.8 changes things up quite a bit.

Is there a tutorial / training on how to take a high poly model and turn it into low poly via decimation and get the normal / bump map from it using 2.8 and higher?

Comment: so you mean you need to make a low poly from a high poly? What are the specific problems you meet in 2.8 compared to 2.7?

Comment: Hello :). Baking normals works the same in 2.8+ as far as I can tell.

Comment: The workflow I used in 2.79 is definitely not the same in 2.8.  Creating materials seems different, getting the node view is different to set on the material, etc.  It might simply be that the real answer is "how do you use the UI changes to achieve the workflow"